# ubuntu 14.04.1 keyboard issues

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, vmware

I am using ubuntu 14.04.1 on VMWare workstation 12. I did some ntp server changes on the machine and after that my keyboard is not working properly.

For example : when I try to input - , I will get = and if I try = , there is nothing shown. Also / is also showing nothing.

I have tried many fixes given in this forum and none of those worked. Also there are other VMs working on the VMWare platform and they do not have any issues with the keyboard.

Comment: did you resolve your issue with answer bellow?

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong keyboard layout selected.

You need to go to the Settings->Keyboard and there select the layout of your keyboard.

Comment: Nope. The only way I could fix it was to restart the VNCserver application that I use to login into my server. I do not think that the issue was with my Ubuntu as all other Ubuntu VMs on my server had the same issue.